# Kendo GridView cell value alias

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, kendo-grid

I want to change the value of the IsActive column from True and False to Yes and No. The code is as follows:

```
             @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Silverback.Vitae.Core.Models.FormModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Width(100).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center;" });
    columns.Bound(p => p.FormID).ClientTemplate("#= actionTemplate(data) #").Width(300).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Action").Sortable(false);

})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetForms", "Forms"))
)
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClientTemplate is the thing that will bring you to success. The same is explained in the FAQ [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq).

ClientTemplate(" #= IsActive ? 'Foo' : 'Bar' #")